# Как настроить image mongo docker container?

Tags: docker, mongodb, dockerfile

Всем привет.

Хочу создать юзера в монго контейнере после запуска контейнера.

Это получилось сделать посредством docker-compose:

```
services:
  mongo:
    image : mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    # volumes:
      # - ./mongo_db_data_container:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin

  mongosettings:
    image : mongo:latest
    container_name: mongoClientTemp
    links:
      - "mongo:mongo"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    # command: sh -c "while ! mongo --host mongo -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase admin --eval  'db.getSiblingDB(\"ShareLinker\").createUser({user:\"Sr233\", pwd:\"greatPassword_QWErty\", roles:[{role:\"readWrite\",db:\"ShareLinker\"}]});' > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 0.1; done" 
    command: sh -c "sleep 15 && mongo --host mongo -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase admin --eval  'db.getSiblingDB(\"ShareLinker\").createUser({user:\"Sr233\", pwd:\"greatPassword_QWErty\", roles:[{role:\"readWrite\",db:\"ShareLinker\"}]});'"
```

Теперь же я хочу сделать это в докер файле.
Пытался сделать так:

```
# VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]

# ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
# ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminimda

EXPOSE 27017

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "sleep 15 && mongo -u admin -p adminimda --authenticationDatabase admin --eval  'db.getSiblingDB(\"ShareLinker\").createUser({user:\"Sr233\", pwd:\"greatPassword_QWErty\", roles:[{role:\"readWrite\",db:\"ShareLinker\"}]});'"]
```

Но не работает, т.к. команды RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT запускаются ПЕРЕД началом запуска контейнера, а мне нужно после.

Есть ли такая возможность ?

Comment: *"не работает"* не является описанием проблемы. Команды CMD, ENTRYPOINT запускаются ПОСЛЕ запуска контейнера. А если стартовая команда сложная, то ее лучше помещать в отдельный скрипт в контейнере.

Comment: "не работает" имеется ввиду что при нормальной работе контейнера докера, появляются логи от монги. При этом появляется возможность зайти в консоль докера и подключиться к дб. А не работает, следовательно нет логов, а после 15 секунд ожидания (в команде ENTRYPOINT) запускается скрипт, который исполняется ДО запуска монги. Надеюсь понятно объяснил :)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте sh скрипт и положите его в контейнер в папку `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` и дайте права на исполнение. Все файлы с расширением .sh лежащие в этой папке будут исполняться при старте контейнера.

Фрагмент Dockerfile для того чтобы сделать то, что я предлагаю:

```
COPY ./init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось реализовать это посредством следующих действий:
DockerFile

```
FROM mongo:latest

# VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]

ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminimda
ENV ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
ENV ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=adminimda

EXPOSE 27017/tcp

COPY ./main.sh ./main.sh

CMD ["bash", "./main.sh"]
```

main.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting"

mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 &

echo "Go to the bed"

sleep 15

echo "Waking up"
echo "Working"

mongo --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("ShareLinker").createUser({user:"Sr233", pwd:"greatPassword_QWErty", roles:[{role:"readWrite",db:"ShareLinker"}]});'

echo "Done"

wait
```